# Pyomo "data = None" output error

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, pyomo

Thanks so much for looking into my problem! I am new to pyomo and now trying to use it to solve a concrete model.

Here is part of my codes:

——— (edited)

```
def objective_rule(model):
        ans = sum(model.DAEB[t] * model.DAEP[t] for t in model.t)
        ans -= sum(model.DARUP[t] * model.RU[t] + model.DARDP[t] * model.RD[t] for t in model.t)
        ans += sum(0.5 * (sum(model.penalty[t, w]) + sum(-model.RTEP[t] * (model.DAEB[t] - ((model.RTRD[t, w] * model.RU[t]) +
               sum(model.veh_pwer_dem[t, v, w] for v in model.v))))) for t in model.t for w in model.w)
        ans += 0.95 * (model.epslon + 1 / (0.5) * sum(0.01 * model.miu[w] for w in model.w))
        return ans
```

- t is defined as a set [0:23], time hour of a day;
- w is defined as [0,1], it's different scenarios;
- v is [0:29], 30 different samples.

Before defining the objective function, I have also defined a bunch of constraints relating with the above model variables.

Everything runs smoothly except till the last step, pyomo gives:

——— (edited)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 61, in <module>
    myresult = result.solve(project, pricefile, reg_dispatch, SOC=0, SOC_margin=0.05)

  line 56, in solve
    opti_model, result = self.Fr_optimal_bidding_optimization(self.vehicles, pricefile, reg_dispatch, SOC)

  line 347, in Fr_optimal_bidding_optimization
    model.objective = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=minimize, doc='minimize the total cost')

  line 483, in __setattr__
    self.add_component(name, val)

  line 849, in add_component
    val.construct(data)

  line 307, in construct
    tmp = _init_rule(_self_parent)

  line 337, in objective_rule
    sum(model.veh_pwer_dem[t, v, w] for v in model.v))))) for t in model.t for w in model.w)

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for objective objective:
  line 337, in <genexpr>
    TypeError: '_GeneralVarData' object is not iterable
    sum(model.veh_pwer_dem[t, v, w] for v in model.v))))) for t in model.t for w in model.w)

ERROR: Constructing component 'objective' from data=None failed:
TypeError: '_GeneralVarData' object is not iterable
    TypeError: '_GeneralVarData' object is not iterable
```

First of all, I am really confused about the `_GeneralVarData` object and don't know what it is referring to and second, I can't see a problem in my objective function, so if anyone could provide any kind of advice will be greatly appreciated!!

(I am also new to "stackoverflow," apologize at front if my question is not clearly stated!)

Teng

Comment: I would first suggest commenting out portions of the expression until you can isolate which part of the expression causes this error. It's hard to look at a large expression like this and pick out the problem.

Comment: Hi Gabe! Thanks so much for the advice. I've re-edited my post.

Comment: Even with the edited post, it's not clear why you're seeing this error.  I think we need to see the definitions of the associated variables.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is triggered by the following code in your second to last line:

```
sum(model.veh_pwer_dem[t, v, w])
```

This attempts to treat the (scalar) `model.veh_pwer_dem[t, v, w]` as an iterable and sum over its keys (indices).  There also appear to be other problems with the logical structure of your expression.  I would highly recommend breaking the expression apart into smaller chunks that will help you to keep things clear.  For example:

```
def objective_rule(model):
    ans = sum(model.DAEB[t] * model.DAEP[t] for t in model.t)
    ans -= sum(model.DARUP[t] * model.RU[t] + model.DARDP[t] * model.RD[t] for t in model.t)
    ans += sum(0.5 * ( sum(model.penalty[t, w] for t in model.t for w in model.w) + # ...
    #...
    return ans
```

As to what a `_GeneralVarData` object is.  `_GeneralVarData` objects are an internal Pyomo structure used to represent an actual optimization variable that is part of an indexed `Var` component (you may occasionally alse see `_SimpleVar`, which is the internal implementation used for non-indexed `Var` components).  As a rule in Pyomo (and Python in general), methods, attributes, and classes beginning with an underscore (`_`) are "private" to the implementation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your comments. I edited my post according to your method and I think you are right. It turns out to still be the "model.veh_pwer_dem[t, v, w]" problem.

Comment: Your edited objective rule still has problems with `sum()` expressions that are not summing over generators.  For example, in your first `+=`, `sum(model.penalty[t, w])` is not legal, and the `sum(-model.RTEP[t] * #...` has no "`for ... in ...`" (so isn't a proper generator / list that python can sum over)